# How to rollback rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

i have a trouble here. I did a mistake, i tried this "rails app:update" on terminal. And now inside my routes, everything has gone. How to rollback this command? thanks

Comment: Do you use any version control system?

Comment: i dont know what control system is.. how to check this out?

Comment: Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_version-control_software https://git-scm.com